# Controlling flow with nested promises in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, promise, bluebird

I'm having trouble controlling the flow of my method using promises:

```
//FIND CHECKED OUT FILES
getCheckedOutFiles = function () {
    console.log('Get checked out files');
    var d = $q.defer();

    // Store final results and pass to then callback
    var checkedOutFiles = window.x = [];

    // Promise, returns collection with all sites 
    SiteService.getAllSites()
        .then(sites => {
            // For each site get lists then get items matching filter
            sites.forEach(function (site) {
                var web = new $pnp.Web(site.url);

                return web.lists
                    .filter("BaseTemplate eq 101")
                    .get() // Returns promise with all lists matching filter 
                    .then(lists => {
                        // Go through each list and find matching item 
                        lists.forEach(function (list) {
                            web.lists.getByTitle(list.Title).items
                                .filter("CheckoutUser ne null")
                                .expand("File, File/Author, File/ModifiedBy, File/CheckedOutByUser")
                                .get() // Returns promise with all items matching filter 
                                .then(files => {
                                    // Loop through each item, get properties, add to collection 
                                    files.forEach(function (f) {
                                        var fileObject = {
                                            fileName: f.File.Name,
                                            fileUrl: f.File.ServerRelativeUrl,
                                            absoluteUrl: f.File.ServerRelativeUrl,
                                            checkedTo: f.File.CheckedOutByUser.Title,
                                            modified: f.Modified,
                                            modifiedBy: f.File.ModifiedBy.Title,
                                            createdBy: f.File.Author.Title,
                                            created: f.Created,
                                            version: f.File.UIVersionLabel
                                        };
                                        // Add file to collection 
                                        checkedOutFiles.push(fileObject);
                                    }, this);
                                })
                                .catch(e => {
                                    console.log(e);
                                });
                        });
                        // "Ideally" - When all files retrieved return collection of results 
                        d.resolve(checkedOutFiles);
                        return null;
                    })
                    .catch(e => {
                        console.log(e);
                    });
            }, this);
            return null;
        });
    return d.promise;
};

// Returns promise with all checkedout file 
getCheckedOutFiles().then(files => {
    console.log("RESULTS", files);
    d.resolve(files);
});
```

I'm noticing the `console.log("RESULTS", files);` will print out before the calls are completed. After the calls are done, `window.x` will contain the expected data.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for all the promises created and then resolve the parent promise

like this (not tested)

```
//FIND CHECKED OUT FILES
getCheckedOutFiles = function () {
    console.log('Get checked out files');
    var d = $q.defer();

    // Store final results and pass to then callback
    var checkedOutFiles = window.x = [];

    // Promise, returns collection with all sites 
    SiteService.getAllSites()
        .then(sites => {
            // For each site get lists then get items matching filter
            sites.forEach(function (site) {
                var web = new $pnp.Web(site.url);

                return web.lists
                    .filter("BaseTemplate eq 101")
                    .get() // Returns promise with all lists matching filter 
                    .then(lists => {
                        let promises = []
                        // Go through each list and find matching item 
                        lists.forEach(function (list) {

                            let prom = web.lists.getByTitle(list.Title).items
                                .filter("CheckoutUser ne null")
                                .expand("File, File/Author, File/ModifiedBy, File/CheckedOutByUser")
                                .get() // Returns promise with all items matching filter 
                                .then(files => {
                                    // Loop through each item, get properties, add to collection 
                                    files.forEach(function (f) {
                                        var fileObject = {
                                            fileName: f.File.Name,
                                            fileUrl: f.File.ServerRelativeUrl,
                                            absoluteUrl: f.File.ServerRelativeUrl,
                                            checkedTo: f.File.CheckedOutByUser.Title,
                                            modified: f.Modified,
                                            modifiedBy: f.File.ModifiedBy.Title,
                                            createdBy: f.File.Author.Title,
                                            created: f.Created,
                                            version: f.File.UIVersionLabel
                                        };
                                        // Add file to collection 
                                        checkedOutFiles.push(fileObject);
                                    }, this);
                                })
                                .catch(e => {
                                    console.log(e);
                                });
                            promises.push(prom)
                        });
                        // "Ideally" - When all files retrieved return collection of results 
                        Promise.all(promises).then(function(){
                            d.resolve(checkedOutFiles);
                        })
                        return null;
                    })
                    .catch(e => {
                        console.log(e);
                    });
            }, this);
            return null;
        });
    return d.promise;
};

// Returns promise with all checkedout file 
getCheckedOutFiles().then(files => {
    console.log("RESULTS", files);
    d.resolve(files);
});
```

Comment: There's more than you show required to fix this.  `return web.lists.filter().get().then()` inside the `sites.forEach()` isn't waiting for that promise either.

Comment: Plus this is a promise [anti-pattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns) with the OP's `d.resolve()` where there's no need to wrap all this in another promise.

Answer (score 1):

These are the things that need fixing:

1. You have two separate loops where you have promises to manage.  You need to collect those promises in an array and then use `Promise.all()` on them to know when all the promises from the loop are done.
2. You are using an anti-pattern by creating the `d` promise and then resolving it manually.  Instead, you should return the `SiteService.getAllSites().then()` promise and then inside of that, return promises to chain so everything is linked (including proper error handling).
3. Your `.catch()` handlers that just log are "eating" errors.  If you `.catch()` and don't rethrow, it turns that promise into a resolved promise, thus "eating" the error and not propagating it.

Here's how you can fix those:

```
//FIND CHECKED OUT FILES
function getCheckedOutFiles() {
    console.log('Get checked out files');

    // Store final results and pass to then callback
    var checkedOutFiles = window.x = [];

    // Promise, returns collection with all sites 
    return SiteService.getAllSites().then(sites => {
            // For each site get lists then get items matching filter
            var promises = [];
            sites.forEach(function (site) {
                var web = new $pnp.Web(site.url);

                promises.push(web.lists
                    .filter("BaseTemplate eq 101")
                    .get() // Returns promise with all lists matching filter 
                    .then(lists => {
                        // Go through each list and find matching item 
                        var promises2 = [];
                        lists.forEach(function (list) {
                            promises2.push(web.lists.getByTitle(list.Title).items
                                .filter("CheckoutUser ne null")
                                .expand("File, File/Author, File/ModifiedBy, File/CheckedOutByUser")
                                .get() // Returns promise with all items matching filter 
                                .then(files => {
                                    // Loop through each item, get properties, add to collection 
                                    files.forEach(function (f) {
                                        var fileObject = {
                                            fileName: f.File.Name,
                                            fileUrl: f.File.ServerRelativeUrl,
                                            absoluteUrl: f.File.ServerRelativeUrl,
                                            checkedTo: f.File.CheckedOutByUser.Title,
                                            modified: f.Modified,
                                            modifiedBy: f.File.ModifiedBy.Title,
                                            createdBy: f.File.Author.Title,
                                            created: f.Created,
                                            version: f.File.UIVersionLabel
                                        };
                                        // Add file to collection 
                                        checkedOutFiles.push(fileObject);
                                    }, this);
                                })
                                .catch(e => {
                                    console.log(e);
                                    // propagate error
                                    throw e;
                                }));
                        });
                        return Promise.all(promises2);
                    }).catch(e => {
                        console.log(e);
                        // propagate error
                        throw e;
                    }));
            }, this);
            return Promise.all(promises).then(() => {
                // make checkedOutFiles by the final resolve value
                return checkedOutFiles;
            });
        });
};

// Returns promise with all checkedout file 
getCheckedOutFiles().then(files => {
    console.log("RESULTS", files);
}).catch(err => {
    // handle error here
});
```

This could be simplified somewhat by using `Promise.map()` in the Bluebird promise library which will iterate an array, calling a promise producing function and wait for all the promises to be done (a combination of `.each()` and `Promise.all()`).